# ExecutorService doens't work

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, blockingqueue

I have problem using Executorservice

I implemented Consumer-Producer Pattern

Main

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10000);

    Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    Runnable consumer1 = new Consumer(queue);
    Runnable consumer2 = new Consumer(queue);
    Runnable consumer3 = new Consumer(queue);

    producer.start();
    executorService.submit(consumer1);
    executorService.submit(consumer2);
    executorService.submit(consumer3);

    executorService.shutdown();


}
}
```

Producer

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Producer implements Runnable{
public BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10000);

public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public synchronized void run() {

    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        try {
            //System.out.println("i = " + i);
            queue.put(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Consumer

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

public BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(10000);

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            //queue.take(); // case 1
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Consumer : " + queue.take()); // case 2

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

I wonder why (Consumer.java) case 1 is not working,
but case 2 is fine

*It print noting and never stopping* (This comment isn't good. Ignore it ㅠㅠ)

I just wonder, Why case 1 is not Stop.

Is there something in System.out.println or BlockingQueue?

(Poducer.java also. If i added print i in Producer.java then Throws InterruptedException)

May be I don't know java and thread well.

Please help me ;(
(My English isn't good, Sorry)

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Why would calling `queue.take()` print anything?

Comment: Sorry, My English isn't good. I mean if I added queue.take() (not use System.out.println) This Process never stop.  not I fixed queue.empty() check, first line in while loop.

Comment: not (x) now (o) I fixed this. Thank you @JBNizet I should have learned How to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that if the queue ever becomes empty just before the `queue.take()`, the consumer thread will block until something gets added to the queue. Since you do all the adding to the queue prior to starting the consumers, it is a matter of luck whether one of the consumers will get into a blocked state.

It appears that case 2 (with the console output) slows things down enough that no thread gets into this state.  In case 1 processing is so fast that at least one thread finds itself blocked.  When I ran your code I found thread 3 blocked, meaning that probably threads 1 and 2 consumed all entries in the queue before thread 3 even had a chance to get started.

If your usecase involves the queue being filled first by the `Producer` and then running the `Consumer` threads, you should use `poll()` instead of `take()` which will let you detect the condition of running out of elements.